# Using Cloudinary with Heroku

Tags: heroku, cloudinary

I'm trying to use Cloudinary to handle the upload of images in my app. I created a Cloudinary account for it and this works perfectly in production.

I've deployed my app to Heroku and can't managed to successfully connect my Heroku app with Cloudinary. My app appears online but the images stored in Cloudinary don't display + the upload function doesn't work as well - i guess it's because the link with cloudinary is broken so the server doesn't know where to get the images or store the files.

I've first manually added the Cloudinary Url  in Heroku's config vars and it didn't work. I then installed the Cloudinary add-on on Heroku and, when I install it in Ressources, Heroku redirects me to a newly created cloudinary account (it seems that adding the Cloudinary add-on to heroku creates a brand new Cloudinary account).

My problem is that I want to use my existing Cloudinary account in my Heroku app and I can't figure out how to connect both.

in my code, i'm storing my details in an env file, and on the server-side, I'm using my account details like so:

```
require("dotenv").config();

cloudinary.config({
cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET
});
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to tell what may be going on. Is the Cloudinary library added correctly or are you getting a specific error? You mention that "My app appears online but the images stored in Cloudinary don't display + the upload function doesn't work as well", can you share errors you may be seeing there?

Comment: Hi Daniel! thanks a lot for your answer! 

yes, I meant that the page appears with all its elements but the functionality related to Cloudinary (upload images + load previous images that have been uploaded) does not work. Here are the errors that I get in the console (i've built the site using vue.js):


`error in get images - vue instance Error: Request failed with status code 503
    at e.exports (spread.js:25)
    at e.exports (spread.js:25)
    at XMLHttpRequest.l.onreadystatechange`


`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)`